# How to build python project based on pyproject.toml

Tags: python, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I would like to understand current state of Python build systems and requirements management.

Imagine, that I checked out sources of some project that is using poetry (or pipenv). And this project has `pyproject.toml` file with build system specified. Of course I can look into pyproject, see that this one is using Poetry, install poetry and run `poetry install`, but I would like to avoid it.

Question: Is there a build-system-agnostic way to build Python project?

By "build" I mean install all the necessary requirements for the project to be run in-place.

With `requirements.txt` I would achieve that by running `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: `pip install .`? See [PEP 517](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/) and [PEP 518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/).

Comment: @Maciek Your comment is outdated and ought to be deleted now. setuptools supports metadata in pyproject.toml.

Answer (score 15):

To install the project (and its dependencies), recent versions of [*pip*](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) are perfectly capable of doing this:

```
python -m pip install path/to/project
```

or

```
python -m pip install --editable path/to/project
```

To build distributions (*sdist* and *wheel*) of the project, currently [*build*](https://pypi.org/project/build/) is the only *build back-end agnostic* tool I know of:

```
python -m build
```

It is also possible to [use *pip* to build a *wheel*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_wheel/) distribution of the project (but no *sdist*):

```
python -m pip wheel --no-deps path/to/project
```

For the content of the `pyproject.toml` file itself, see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/64151860

Comment: Maybe it's not directly related to the question, but how should the `pyproject.toml` then be formatted? Because I have been trying to get it to work and I couldn't find a good resource on it.

Comment: Yes, a bit out of scope considering the original question. Writing the `pyproject.toml` is build-system-dependent though, so which one are you targetting (_setuptools_, _flit_, _poetry_, etc.)?

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60046331/11138259

Comment: @maarten-vd-Sande For the formatting of `pyproject.toml`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64151860