# Installing numpy before using numpy.distutils.core.setup

Tags: python, numpy, installation, setuptools, f2py

I am using `numpy.distutils` to setup a package (mypackage) that has a frotran module. The problem is that if I do `pip install mypackage` on an environment that does not have numpy, I get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

The easy solution is to ask users (if I manage to have any) to `pip install numpy` before they install my package, but I do not think this is a very *elegant* solution.

I came up with the idea of calling `setuptools.setup` with only `setup_requires=['numpy']` before I import numpy and it seems to work well. This is my `setup.py`:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    setup_requires=[
        'numpy'
    ],)

from numpy.distutils.core import setup, Extension

mod = Extension(name='mypackage.amodule', sources=['source/a.f90'])

setup(name='mypackage',
      packages=['mypackage'],
      ext_modules=[mod],)
```

I honestly don't fully understand what it implies to call an empty `setup()` (no name, no package). **Is this a good solution? Is this somehow a bad practice?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a common issue. How to install a *build-time* dependency? You might want to use a `pyproject.toml` file and take advantage of the `build-system` feature. See [PEP517](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/). And an example here:

```
[build-system]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
requires = ["setuptools", "numpy"]
```

Use the [`pep517` tool](https://pypi.org/project/pep517/) to build the distributions (*sdist* and *wheel*).

Comment: I have tried this but it does not seem to build the module (amodule). Could it be that I have to use a different backend?

Comment: @Felix Maybe add an update to your question, to show your progress. In your `setup.py` make sure to remove the first `setuptools.setup(...)` call. The rest seems fine.

Comment: I was wrong; the error was caused by a completely different problem. Sorry

Comment: It seems that this will not install numpy. The build works correctly, but `python -c "import numpy"` returns an error. **So, if you need numpy for your package, you should still have it listed in `install_requires` of the `setup.py`**. Is that correct?

Comment: @Felix Yes, _build-time_ and _install-time_ dependencies can be two completely different lists. So eventually some dependencies might need to be listed in both, like _numpy_ in your case apparently.